# unreported exception filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, io

I am trying to make a stream, so I can read 2 lines from .txt file to two string variables. I tried try/catch, but still have an ureported exception error.

```
public class Shad1 {
    public void myMethod()throws FileNotFoundException {    
        String stringName = new String("");
        String stringNumb = new String("");
        File file = new File ("c:\\input.txt");
        try {
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

            int check = input.read();
            char data = input.readChar();
            while(data != '\n') {
                stringName = stringName + data;
            }

            while (check != -1){ 
                stringNumb = stringNumb + data;}

            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());}
}
```

Comment: You have an unreported exception? How do you know you get an exception then? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Surely the real message is 'unhandled exception: IOException'? And why are you both throwing and catching `FileNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the `read` method: note that this method can also throw an `IOException`. See the docs for the `read` method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])), the declaration is:

```
public final int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

So you'll also need to *catch* `IOException`, or report that your method *throws* `IOException`.

Note that you don't need to do *both*, so in your example code, you can similarly choose to report that your method throws `FileNotFoundException` *or* declare it in a `catch` block: you don't need both (unless some other part of the code in the method might generate an unhandled `FileNotFoundException`).